# Does bean directly removed from container right after @PreDestroy?

Tags: java, spring

I plan to make some clean up work after Spring application is shutting down, However may questions is whether Spring container remove the bean right after `@PreDestroy` is complete, or there is still little time for the bean to do something, meaning methods in the bean outside `@PreDestroy` can still keep running until Spring container recycle the bean.

I am thinking of two solutions:

```
//----> Solution 1
private boolean onRemoval = false;
public void methodA(){
    if(onRemoval){
         //do something
         //so only if application is shutting down and 
         //hit this point then we do clean up
    }
}
@PreDestroy
public void turnOnFlag(){
    onRemoval = true;
}

//----> Solution 2
// no flag or indicator, clean up only in 
//@PreDestroy because nothing can be done 
//after @PreDestroy method is done
@PreDestroy
public void cleanUp(){
    //clean up work
}
```

My question is does solution 1 feasible? I just want to confirm that whether bean is directly recycled right after `@PreDestroy` is complete, if so could you please share the source of the doc

Comment: Where is methodA called from in option 1? And why don’t you like option 2 as the simplest approach?

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar thanks. MethodA in option 1 can be referred by other beans while it is running. I am trying to let Method A wrap keep making progress if bean hasn't been recycled yet. I will choose Option 2 if only bean will be recycled right after `@PostDestroy` method is complete, however I can't find supporting document about it

Comment: There’s no such thing as recycling a bean. Also, it sounds like you’re making a lot of assumptions about the order of operations at shutdown for option 1, and you’ve not yet furnished any reason for it to exist. I believe the answer is clear as daylight, go for option 2.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Recycling or removing or terminating, I think eventually the bean will no longer managed by Spring container, between the end of `@PreDestroy` and the bean being terminated, is there a gap or the latter occurs right after the former? I couldn't find any document about it.